# Need help implementing Bluetooth in my Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am creating an app for an arduino thermometer, to connect via Bluetooth.
However I am finding it very difficult to implement Bluetooth in Android studio I looked at the example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection), I am having errors implementing it.

It's line 65 in the "MyBluetoothService" class that is creating the error.

The error is: Cannot resolve method "obtainMessage(int, int, int, byte[])

The link to the full [code](https://github.com/Joha6210/AndroidApp)

And the faulty code here:

```
        public void run() {

             mmBuffer = new byte[1024];

             int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to know the full error message and stack trace, otherwise we won't know what's going wrong with your code :)

Comment: I think you picked the wrong example to use\. The example you point to uses Bluetooth Classic to connect the devices. Although this is possible, I think you would be better off using Bluetooth Low Energy. Although part of the same standard the comms part is very different.